# Download photos in zip file

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hi guys and thanks so much for any help you can give. here in this code in uploading the img to a mysql data base using a form,this the data base.

**database**

```
CREATE TABLE `user_pic` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `img` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    `img_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `upload_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Here i load all the photos in a variable

**load_img.php**

```
$couple_login_id = $_SESSION['users']['id'];
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_pic WHERE user_id = $couple_login_id");
$statement->execute();
$fotos = $statement->fetchAll();
```

An here i loop all the images and display the images on the html

**gallery.php**

```
    <?php foreach($fotos as $foto):?>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 item-photo">
        <div class="photo">
          <?php echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $foto['img'] ).'"/>';?>
          <?php echo '<a class="search zoom fancybox" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $foto['img'] ).'"><span class="icon-search"></span></a>';?>
          <?php if($_SESSION['users']["user_rol"] == 1):?>
            <a class="star" href="#"><span class="icon-star"></span></a>
          <?php endif;?>
          <a class="download" href="#"><span class="icon-download"></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

This the code to download all the photo on a zip file.
**download_zip.php**

```
  $zip = new ZipArchive();

  # create a temp file & open it
  $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
  $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

  # loop through each file
  foreach($fotos as $file){

      # download file
      $download_file = file_get_contents($file['img']);

      #add it to the zip
      $zip->addFile($download_file);

  }

  # close zip
  $zip->close();

      # send the file to the browser as a download
     header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=wedding_photos.zip");
     header("Content-length: " . filesize('wedding_photos.zip'));
     header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
     header("Expires: 0"); 
     readfile('wedding_photos.zip');
```

The problemis that when i create the zip file and download it, i can open it because sed that file has a unknow format or is damaged. i don´t if there is something wrong with the code or is because the the way the photos are stored on the data base. Thanks for the help you can give to me. :D

Comment: First of all, it looks like you are calling basename($path) on an array. It needs a $path {string}

Comment: in wich part do you mean...?

Comment: I think you are using addFile with wrong params. You should add file by path. See docs: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using binary data instead of files you should use `addFromString` method. So you can change code to this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

// create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.', '');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// loop through each file
foreach ($fotos as $file) {
    //add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString($file['img_name'], $file['img']);
}

// close zip
$zip->close();
```

Comment: Alex now the problem is that i can extract the photos because sed that the files are damaged XD

Comment: Ok, try to output **$file['img']** or just try to save it. Maybe it does damaged

Comment: yeah i try to save it, but well sed the files are damaged, any way to fix that issue....?

Comment: ok i send you link on pinterest [link](https://es.pinterest.com/pin/30188259983073004/)

Comment: I mean binary data from DB

Comment: XD here is the link again [Error](https://es.pinterest.com/pin/30188259983073031/)

Comment: Ok, try to save those binary to file from MySQL client application. If image open as well then maybe you can try to set charset connection with database 'utf8'

Comment: I try but doesn´t work
`$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. $db .';charset=utf8', $user_name, $pass);
      $connection->exec('SET NAMES utf8');`

Comment: Can you send me an archive? and those table for sure alexslipknot@europe.com. I'll see later

Answer (score 0):

Set your path

> $zip->addFile("$file_path",$download_file);

Add Content-length header describing size of zip file in bytes.

```
header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=wedding_photos.zip");
header("Content-length: " . filesize('wedding_photos.zip'));
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
readfile('wedding_photos.zip');
```

Comment: Give me the same result.

Comment: ok, already made the change but still sending the same message whent i try to open it

Comment: Change add from string to addFile.. Eg:  $zip->addFile($download_file);

Comment: Same error message, if weird because download the file but sed unknow format or damaged.

Comment: Updated my code and hardcode the strings. and check it once again to resolve the issue.

Comment: I did, but i still resiving the same error when i open the zip

Comment: addFile using filePath. Not the file content

Comment: instead we can add "/" as path.  $zip->addFile('/', $download_file);

Comment: Guys i thing is that the photos are on a mysql database that im get and store on the $foto variables as an array. in that case wich would be path...?

Comment: There is no path. You images are binary. Added possible solution